# C# deserialize xml get element value

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to get the value of the XmlElement out of the Translation.

When I debug the code the value is null. I'm trying to get the value of the `Translations.Section.Translation` in `Translation.cs`. I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong and why. Can anyone explain to me what I need to do?

I came this far but I don't know how to fill the value.

#### XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Translations code="nl" description="Dutch" xmlns="urn:Test.Translations">

  <Section name="Module">
    <Translation key="SystemConfiguration">Systeem configuratie</Translation>
  </Section>

  <Section name="Feature">
    <Translation key="Feature">Feature</Translation>
    <Translation key="Name">Naam</Translation>
    <Translation key="IsEnabled">Actief</Translation>
  </Section>

</Translations>
```

#### Translations.cs

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:Test.Translations", ElementName = "Translations", DataType = "string", IsNullable = true)]
public class Translations
{
    [XmlAttribute("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Section")]
    public List<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}
```

#### Section.cs

```
public class Section
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Translation")]
    public List<Translation> Translations { get; set; }
}
```

#### Translation.cs

```
public class Translation
{
    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    //TODO Get value (This is null)
    [XmlElement("Translation")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

#### program.cs

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Translations), "");
using (var reader = new StreamReader(xmlFilePath))
{
    var translationFile = (Translations) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `[XmlText]` attribute:

```
public class Translation
{
    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [XML2CSharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) to generate class than try again and see if you still get null.

Generated code for your XML looks like this:
(You can remove unwanted properties)

```
/* 
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*/
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Translation", Namespace="urn:Test.Translations")]
public class Translation {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Section", Namespace="urn:Test.Translations")]
public class Section {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Translation", Namespace="urn:Test.Translations")]
    public List<Translation> Translation { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Translations", Namespace="urn:Test.Translations")]
public class Translations {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Section", Namespace="urn:Test.Translations")]
    public List<Section> Section { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}

}
```

Comment: I prefer clean code over generated code. `mm8` has the solution for me. But thanks for thinking with me. Windows also has a auto generate xsd out of xml and you can generate a c# file out if it with xsd.exe.

Comment: No problem. That is why I said you can remove all unwanted properties before using the code or just use it for reference for debugging.

Comment: Ah I could have done that as well. I didn't think of that.